# Error when starting new activity from menu click

Tags: java, android

I am new to android development so there is probably something simple that is wrong. If you need any more info I will be glad to give that to you. Thanks in advance.

I am trying to add a button in my navdrawer.class. This is what I have.

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.new_account:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddAccountActivity.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            break;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

I get an error.

Comment: please post the stacktrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you´re into a `fragment` you must use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddAccountActivity.class);
```

or

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), AddAccountActivity.class);
```

for example see the context used in your `Toast` (`getActivity()`)

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "This Will Create  A New Account.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write

```
Intent intent = new Intent(AddAccountActivity.this, AddAccountActivity.class);
```

instead of

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddAccountActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Am I right that `this` is the fragment instance? If this is the case, thats your problem. The intent constructor needs a context and an activity class to work.

Fragment does not inherit from context. You can get the underlying activity with the `getActivity()` method.

try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddAccountActivity.class);
```